# How to receive a confirmation for a picture being saved when takePicture() is being used

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-camera, handler, picturecallback

How to receive a confirmation for a picture being saved when `takePicture()` is being used such that `finish()` can be used after that.

I used

```
camera.takePicture(null,null,p);
finish();
```

But by using this I'm unable to get the picture used since finish is called before the picture being used.

I don't want to use `handler` and `AsyncTask` didn't worked don't know why.

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you post the code for the variable `p`? couldn't you call `finish()` there?

Comment: p is a class that contains ``onPictureTaken(byte[] data)`` where I'm saving the image.